# How do I create a "here document" within a shell function?

Tags: linux, macos, shell-script

I'm working my way through William Shotts Jr.'s great [The Linux Command Line](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php) on my Mac OSX 10.7.5 system. 90% of the linux that Shotts covers is close enough to Darwin that I can figure out or GTEM to figure out what's going on.  I've made it to chapter 27 on "Writing Shell Scripts" and am getting hung up creating "here files" within a function.

I get an `syntax error: unexpected end of file` error when I include the following function:

```
report_uptime () {
  cat <<- _EOF_
    <H2>System Uptime</H2>
    <PRE>$(uptime)</PRE>
    _EOF_
  return
}
```

The error goes away if I use the following function placeholder:

```
report_uptime () {
  return
}
```

Also, elsewhere in the script, outside of a function I use the `cat << _EOF_` format to create a "here file" with no trouble:

```
cat << _EOF_
<HTML>
      <HEAD>
            <TITLE>$TITLE</TITLE>
      </HEAD>
      <BODY>
            <H1>$TITLE</H1>
            <P>$TIME_STAMP</P>
            $(report_uptime)
            $(report_disk_space)
            $(report_home_space)
      </BODY>
</HTML>
_EOF_
```

If anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong I would be grateful!

Comment: The _EOF_ token must be the first thing on the line, without any leading white spaces.

Comment: That worked for me, @Ярослав_Рахматуллин.  I don't think that the `[-]` is an option for Darwin's here files.  `cat << _EOF_` not `cat <<- _EOF_`

Comment: that's a shame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[If the redirection operator is ‘<<-’, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing delimiter. This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents)

If that does not work as documented, try moving the *EOF* token to the very beginning of the line (remove all white spaces).

Comment: This should work regardless of the system, unless the bash version is broken on your system.

Comment: Thanks @Ярослав_Рахматуллин  Though adding the `-` to `<<` didn't solve my problem, removing the whitespace before the `_EOF_` did.  Perhaps "here documents" with `cat <<` works in Darwin but not `cat <<-`.  It's a shame since `<<-` is so useful.  Move your comment into your answer and I will accept it.  Addendum: bash may in fact be broken.  Possibly broken by me, possibly Mac's Darwin's limitations...

Comment: @BenU, note that the man page is very specific here: **tab characters** not **whitespace**

Comment: @glennjackman Using spaces instead of tabs could indeed be the source of my problem.  I've arranged my text editor to use two spaces instead of tab by default.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I thought the `heredoc` did not work in my bash too, and I tested it both in OS X and Linux.

I'm using `VScode`, and finally I found the problem was in my tab settings. We should use the `Indent Using Tabs`, not the `Indent Using Spaces`. And after I made the settings correct, the `heredoc` indent functionality with `<<-` mark works all the time.

[vscode settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf9R8.png)

Answer (score -1):

Ok - reading the exact same book myself now and just finished working through this step.  I too am using a mac but also use an Ubuntu Virtual Box to follow along with the text.

The here document inside of the report_uptime function is the culprit causing your unexpected end of file.  Despite a function's syntax, remove the white space leading the closing _EOF_.

To recreate this issue, I'll use this example:

[here_function_script1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dTPw.png)

Until the shell reads the _EOF_ at the very beginning of the line, anything that precedes it is considered as the 'body of text' and the here document is never closed.  In this case, it never sees the _EOF_ , creating your syntax error.  The shell respects the here document syntax over the function syntax.

[here_function_script2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ2Le.png)

Comment: Why did you choose to provide screenshots of scripts instead of just providing the scripts themselves?

Comment: Because I'm using VirtualBox to host my Ubuntu instance on a Mac and haven't configured it to accept copy/paste from the guest OS to the host OS.